# How to add swipe able tabs in Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am using `FragmentTabHost` to add tabs in Fragment

Below is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ExploreFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"),
                ContactUsFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment C"),
                MyProfileFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Fragment D"),
                RaiseCampaignFragment.class, null);


        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And my xml is like :

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

I have added 3 tabs successfully, but I am unable to swipe them or can say they are not swipeable.

How to make the tabs swipeable?

**Please Help!!**

Comment: You need to add viewpager for swipe functionality

Comment: Check out this link  http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: but viewpager needs getSupportFragmentManager(); you can not use in fragment.

Comment: You use getChildFragmentManager() in fragments

Comment: @AbhayBohra Thanks a lot.. it worked..

Answer (score 2):

You can create swipe views in your app using the [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) widget, available in the `Support Library`. The `ViewPager` is a layout widget in which each child view is a separate page (a separate tab) in the layout.

To set up your layout with `ViewPager`, add a `<ViewPager>` element to your XML layout. For example, if each page in the swipe view should consume the entire layout, then your layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To insert child views that represent each page, you need to hook this layout to a [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html).

Checkout [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tab_layout"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```